# gsoap c file read

Tags: c++, file, gsoap

I am new to C++. I have written upload file wcf in c# and have gsoap2.8 to generate header.h file.

This is my upload file wcf service in c#.

```
public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
    {
        FileStream targetStream = null;
        Stream sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;

        string uploadFolder = @"C:\temp\upload\copyHere";
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);

        using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            //read from the input stream in 6K chunks
            //and save to output stream
            const int bufferLen = 65000;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
            {
                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            targetStream.Close();
            sourceStream.Close();
        }

    }
```

Below is header.h code generated by gsoap2.8 from a wsdl:

```
class SOAP_CMAC xsd__base64Binary
{
public:
    unsigned char *__ptr;
    int __size;
    char *id;   /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    char *type; /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    char *options;  /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    struct soap *soap;  /* transient */
public:
    virtual int soap_type() const { return 8; } /* = unique id SOAP_TYPE_xsd__base64Binary */
    virtual void soap_default(struct soap*);
    virtual void soap_serialize(struct soap*) const;
    virtual int soap_put(struct soap*, const char*, const char*) const;
    virtual int soap_out(struct soap*, const char*, int, const char*) const;
    virtual void *soap_get(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
    virtual void *soap_in(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
             xsd__base64Binary() { xsd__base64Binary::soap_default(NULL); }
    virtual ~xsd__base64Binary() { }
};

class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__RemoteFileInfo
{
public:
    xsd__base64Binary FileByteStream;   /* SOAP 1.2 RPC return element (when namespace qualified) */    /* required element of type ns2:StreamBody */
    struct soap *soap;  /* transient */
public:
    virtual int soap_type() const { return 14; } /* = unique id SOAP_TYPE__ns1__RemoteFileInfo */
    virtual void soap_default(struct soap*);
    virtual void soap_serialize(struct soap*) const;
    virtual int soap_put(struct soap*, const char*, const char*) const;
    virtual int soap_out(struct soap*, const char*, int, const char*) const;
    virtual void *soap_get(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
    virtual void *soap_in(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
             _ns1__RemoteFileInfo() { _ns1__RemoteFileInfo::soap_default(NULL); }
    virtual ~_ns1__RemoteFileInfo() { }
};
```

Here is my test.cpp code. I need to read a file into **xsd__base64Binary** so I can assign to  remoteFile.FileByteStream

```
BasicHttpBinding_USCOREITransferService svc;
__ns1__UploadFileResponse uploadRespond;
_ns1__RemoteFileInfo remoteFile;

std::string path = "C:\\temp\\upload\\test.txt";
```

i need to read above file into 
        ????

```
remoteFile.FileByteStream = ?
```

so I can call webservice uploadFile as below:

```
int result = svc.__ns1__UploadFile(&remoteFile, uploadRespond);
```

Thank you in advance,

JH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in c:

```
    unsigned char * buffer; 
    int fileLen;    
    FILE *file;

    //OPEN FILE
    file = fopen(name, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
        return;
    }

    //GET FILE LENGTH
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //ALLOCATE MEMORY
    buffer=(unsigned char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error! :( ");
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    //READ FILE CONTENTS INTO BUFFER AND CLOSE FILE
    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    //USE THE BUFFER ....


    //FREE YOUR ALLOCATED BUFFER
    free(buffer);
```

In your **remoteFile**:

```
remoteFile.FileByteStream.__ptr = buffer;
remoteFile.FileByteStream.__size = fileLen;
```

**UPDATE: allocate memory with soap_malloc**

Use:

```
buffer=(unsigned char *)soap_malloc(soap,fileLen+1);
```

Instead of:

```
buffer=(unsigned char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
```

Remove:

```
free(buffer);
```

Allocation will be done in the context of the current operation, the **free** will be done by the gsoal library when the operation is done.

Comment: I am trying to do the same.... I am implement an SOAP Client with MTOM attachments... And... How is it added configuration parameters? like this:
`Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <example.zip>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="example.zip"`